# ayuda a insertar valores a mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql

No puedo insertar valores a mi tabla en mysql con php creo que el problema es con el `include_once` o con el archivo de `conexion.php`. soy nuevo y estoy intentando hacer un sistema cobro de cuotas de un wisp.

`index.html` que envía usuario y contraseña de la DB

```
<body>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <h1>Ingrese su usuario y contraseña</h1>
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario"><br>
        <input type="password" name="contra" placeholder="Contraseña"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Iniciar Sesión">
    </form>

</body>
```

el php que recibe usuario y contraseña y hace la conexión

```
<body>

    <?php

        session_start();
        
        $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
        $contra = $_POST["contra"];

        $_SESSION['user'] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $contra;
        

        try{
            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas', $_SESSION['user'], $_SESSION['password']);
            header("Location: Bienvenido.php");

        }catch(Exception $e){
            header("Location: incorrecto.php");
        }

    ?>
</body>
```

si el usuario y contraseña son correctos me manda a `bienvenido.html` en el cual se rellenan la información de el cliente a registrar

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user']) || !isset($_SESSION['password'])) {
        header("Location: index.html");
    }
    
    echo "Bienvenido ".$_SESSION['user'];
?>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="newuser.php" >
        <h1>Ingrese los datos a registrar</h1>
        <input type="text" id="Nombre" name="cliente" placeholder="Nómbre de el ciente"><br>
        <input type="text" id="direccion"name="direccion" placeholder="Dirección"><br>
        <input type="number" id="cel" name="cel" placeholder="Número de celular"><br>
        <input type="number" id="dni" name="dni" placeholder="DNI"><br>

        <label from="servicios">Eliga un servicio</label><br>
        <select name="servicios" id="servicios">
            <option value="internet">Internet</option>
            <option value="Cable">Tv Satelital</option>
            <option value="Paquete Completo">Paquete completo</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="number" id="pago_inter" name="pago_inter" class="itemTotalNeto" placeholder="Pago mensual por internet"><br>
        <input type="number" id="pago_tv" name="pago_tv" class="itemTotalNeto" placeholder="Pago mensual Tv"><br>
        <input type="date" name="fecha_instalacion">
        <button type="submit" name="registrar">Registrar</button>

    </form>

</body>
```

si se escribe mal el usuario y/o contraseña me manda a esta pagina que lo que haces es darme un enlace para volver a introducir el usuario y contraseña

```
<body>

    <?php
        session_start();
        echo "El usuario y/o contraseña son incorrectos";
    ?>

    <a href="index.html">Volver a logear</a>
    

</body>
```

este es el archivo `.php` que debería hacer el registro de datos en la tabla de mi DB pero al darle clic en el botón de el archivo `bienvenido.html` me manda directamente al archivo `incorrecto.php` como si hubiera escrito mal el usuario y contraseña y es el único donde incluyo el archivo `conexion.php` que recibe el usuario y contraseña

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user']) || !isset($_SESSION['password'])) {
        header("Location: index.html");
    }

    include_once "login.php";

    $cliente = $_POST["cliente"];
    $lugar = $_POST["direccion"];
    $cel = $_POST["cel"];
    $documento = $_POST["dni"];
    $serv = $_POST["servicios"];
    $inter = $_POST["pago_inter"];
    $tv = $_POST["pago_tv"];
    $fecha = $_POST["fecha_instalacion"];

    $nombre = $cliente;
    $direccion = $lugar;
    $celular = $cel;
    $dni = $documento;
    $paquete = $serv;
    $pago_inter = $inter;
    $pago_tv = $tv;
    $fecha_instalacion = $fecha;


    $sentencia = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO clientes values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
    $resultado = $sentencia->execute([$nombre, $direccion, $celular, $dni, $paquete, $pago_inter, $pago_tv, $fecha_instalacion]);
    
    if ($resultado === true) {
        echo "Se agrego a instalacion pendiente";

    }else{
        echo "No se agrego a instalacion pendiente";
    }


?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, no se necesario abusar de los formatos de texto, la negrita debe  usarse para resaltar algunos textos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En principio, te quería felicitar por la pregunta (bien escrita) y por el código. Si sos nuevo, estás usando PDO, persistiendo en sessión, etc... que son buenas técnicas.

En principio quería decirte esto: cuando hacés la conexión a PDO, el usuario y la contraseña que te pide no es del usuario que se está logueando a tu sitio, si no del usuario y contraseña de la base de datos:
Vos tenés esto:

```
 $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas', $_SESSION['user'], $_SESSION['password']);
```

Por lo que pude entender de tu código, ahí en $_SESSION['user'] y $_SESSION['password'] tenés persistidos los valores del usuario que se está tratando de conectar a tu sitio.

Mysql debería tener un solo usuario y contraseña para conectarse, y nadie lo debería conocer más que vos. Por ende, te recomiendo o bien que lo encapsules bien en tu código, o (mejor) lo tengas separado en un archivo json o yml, y lo leas desde ahí.

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas', "miusuarioDB", "mipassDB");
```

O bien:

```
$configContents = file_get_contents('config/config.json');
$config = json_decode($configContents, true);
$dbConfig = $config["database"];
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbConfig["host"].';dbname='.$dbConfig["dbname"], $dbConfig["user"], $dbConfig["pass"]);
```

Y en tu config.json:

```
{
   "database": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "dbname": "pruebas",
        "user": "miuserDB",
        "pass": "mipassDB"
   }
}
```

Esta es la mejor forma, a mi gusto, ya que podrias tener un archivo por cada environment (prod, dev, etc...) y levantar el archivo de config según ese environment, y no te toca estar haciendo cambios cuando deployás tu proyecto en algo productivo.
Además, ahí podés agregar otras configuraciones y armarte una clase que levante directamente la configuración.

`$Config->getDbUser(); $Config->getDBPass()...`